# .schema for postgres

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

I'm migrating a database from sqlite3 to postgres and am wondering if there are any short tutorials that can teach me the new syntax.

Also, as a short term question, how do I see the schema of a postgres table which is equivalent to `.schema` in sqlite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\d` from within [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS):

```
=> \?
...

Informational
  (options: S = show system objects, + = additional detail)
  \d[S+]                 list tables, views, and sequences
  \d[S+]  NAME           describe table, view, sequence, or index
...

=> \d people
                                           Table "public.people"
         Column         |            Type             |                      Modifiers                      
------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id                     | integer                     | not null default nextval('people_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at             | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at             | timestamp without time zone | not null
...
Indexes:
    "people_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
...
Check constraints:
    "chk_people_latlng" CHECK ((lat IS NULL) = (lng IS NULL))
....
```

You can also root around in the [`information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) if you're not inside `psql`.

Comment: It appears `.schema` generates a CREATE statement for the table.  `\d` is not really an equivalent.

Comment: @Frank: "how do I see the schema", but whatever.

Comment: If someone is learning postgres and trying to get "the new syntax", `\d` is pretty in-bounds. sqlite dot commands are a big part of its shell interface, and backslash meta commands are the precise psql shell analogue. Furthermore `\?`, the second line of this answer, is, to borrow a phrase, a "short tutorial that can teach me the new syntax".

Answer (score 5):

You could use pg_dump command line utility, i.e.:

```
pg_dump --table <table_name> --schema-only <database_name>
```

Depending on your environment you probably need to specify connection options (-h, -p, -U switches).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using psql (and \d... ) then you can

```
\set ECHO_HIDDEN
```

to see the sql for the queries that psql is executing to put together the \d... output-- this is useful not only as sql syntax examples but it also shows you where find, and how to connect, the database metadata.

To get the schema name for a table you can:

```
SELECT  n.nspname AS schema_name,
        c.relname AS table_name
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relname = '<table_name>'
;
```

(don't know how that compares to .schema)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a PostgreSQL Cheat Sheet:

http://www.postgresonline.com/special_feature.php?sf_name=postgresql83_cheatsheet&outputformat=html